# AngularJS ng-click is not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I have an ng-click in my app that is not firing when the element is clicked.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-7" ng-controller="githubController">
  <div class="panel commitPanel">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <th>sha</th>
        <th>Author</th>
        <th>Message</th>
        <th>Date</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

app.js:

```
.controller("githubController",["$scope", function($scope){
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "https://api.github.com/users/jmona789/repos?sort=pushed",
      success: function(repos) {
        for(var i = 0; i < repos.length; i++) {
          var newListItem = buildListGroup(repos[i]);
          $(".list-group").append(newListItem);
        }
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Something went wrong. We are looking into it!");
      }
    });

    function buildListGroup(repoData) {
      var commitsApiUrl = "https://api.github.com/repos/";
      commitsApiUrl += repoData.owner.login + "/";
      commitsApiUrl += repoData.name + "/commits";

      var newLink = $("<a>")
        .attr("url", commitsApiUrl)
        .attr("ng-click", 'buildCommits()')
        .addClass("list-group-item")
        .append(repoData.full_name);
      return newLink;
    }
```

All That works fine and it adds the ng-click to each element^

But when I click each element this function in the controller never fires:

```
    $scope.buildCommits = function(){
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: $(this).attr("url"),
        success: function(commits) {
          $("tbody").empty();
          for(var i = 0; i < commits.length; i++) {
            $("tbody").append(buildTableRow(commits[i]));
          }
        }
      })
      function buildTableRow(commitData) {
        var commitUrl = commitData.html_url;
        var shaTd = $("<td>").append($("<a href="+commitUrl+">").html(commitData.sha).attr("target", "_blank"));
        var authorTd = $("<td>").append(commitData.author.login);
        var messageTd = $("<td>").append(commitData.commit.message);
        var dateTd = $("<td>").append(commitData.commit.author.date);



        return $("<tr>").append(shaTd)
          .append(authorTd)
          .append(messageTd)
          .append(dateTd);
      }
    }
  }])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ng-click isn't working because you aren't compiling the HTML that is returned to the DOM.  However there are a number of issues with your code that will prevent it from working.

- $(".list-group").append(newListItem); 'list-group' class isn't in your view.
- More importantly this isn't really the correct way of doing Angular.  Direct DOM manipulation is rarely needed and often not bad.
- Like @allord said the link has a url and a ng-click. They do one or th other not both.

**The Angular Way Of Doing This**

Use ng-repeat in the HTML view and iterate over a model created in the controller.

**Example View**

```
<div ng-repeat="link in links">
   <a ng-click="buildCommits()" class="list-group-item">  
     {{link.full_name}}
   </a>
</div>
```

**Controller JS**

...

```
success: function(repos) {
      $scope.links = buildLinks(repos);
  },
```

...

```
  function buildLinks(repos) {
    var links = [];
    _.forEach(repos, function(repo) {    
      var commitsApiUrl = "https://api.github.com/repos/";
      commitsApiUrl += repoData.owner.login + "/";
      commitsApiUrl += repoData.name + "/commits";
      links.push({
          commitsApiUrl: commitsApiUrl
          full_name: repo.full_name
      });
    });
    return links;
  }
```

Comment: The build links function is giving me this error: _ is not defined

Comment: Yeah it's pseudo code to illustrate the solution.  The underscore is the lodash library.  Also recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Your code here

```
var newLink = $("<a>")
        .attr("url", commitsApiUrl)
        .attr("ng-click", 'buildCommits()')
        .addClass("list-group-item")
        .append(repoData.full_name);
      return newLink;
```

What exactly is the 'url' attribute of the anchor tag? Try this in place of it

```
var newLink = $("<a>")
        .attr("href", commitsApiUrl)
        .attr("ng-click", 'buildCommits()')
        .addClass("list-group-item")
        .append(repoData.full_name);
      return newLink;
```

I'm confused why you would want ng-click to fire when you have an href attribute applied? You might consider using a different tag with a data attribute.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make sure that ng-app is defined in your html before ng-controller is added. I cannot see it in your code snippet. If it's already exists, That wouldn't be a problem.

Also in the code snippet where you define your link element try to make the href to be '#' and in the click function do the navigation after performing the logic you need to make sure that it will be fired.

Also please try to move DOM manipulation from the controller to a directive as it is the best place for this and keep the controller for doing business logic only.

Answer (score -1):

you need to compile you string with $compile service. inject '$compile' service with your controller

like :

```
function buildListGroup(repoData) {
      var commitsApiUrl = "https://api.github.com/repos/";
      commitsApiUrl += repoData.owner.login + "/";
      commitsApiUrl += repoData.name + "/commits";

      var newLink = $("<a>")
        .attr("url", commitsApiUrl)
        .attr("ng-click", 'buildCommits()')
        .addClass("list-group-item")
        .append(repoData.full_name);
      return $compile(template)($scope);
    }
```

first read http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/07/using-compile-in-angular.aspx

Comment: Compiling whilst accurate isn't a great way to write code.  I personally feel it makes the code very unreadable.

Comment: but @Jones when we want to write HTML from Controller then it's necessary

Comment: In rare circumstances - Yes.  For the code examples shown - above is not good practice.

Comment: so what you think about ReactJS ??

Comment: I love ReactJs - although it's not relevant to the Angular discussion here.